# mongodb: query in deep arrays

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I am using MongoDb to store following JSON. How do I search for all the articles with "2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b" in pageLayouts array.

```
{
    "magazine": {
        "articles": [
            {
                "articleLayouts": [
                    {
                        "pageLayouts": [
                            "2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In MongoDb documentation, they only specify searching for elements in array that only 1 level deep. For example: Searching in "http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/"

```
db.bios.find(
   {
      awards: {
                $elemMatch: {
                     award: "Turing Award",
                     year: { $gt: 1980 }
                }
      }
   }
)
```

How do I search deeper arrays? as in the articles array in first JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

and query as :

```
db.collectionName.find({"magazine.articles":{"$elemMatch":{"articleLayouts":{"$elemMatch":{"pageLayouts":{"$in":["2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b"]}}}}}}).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** for this, in particular the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator as it deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. Thus you can do a $match query further down the pipeline to filter the documents and return the ones that match your criteria.

The following aggregation pipeline will return documents with `"2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b"` in pageLayouts array:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "magazine.articles.articleLayouts.pageLayouts": "2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$articles"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$articles.articleLayouts"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$articles.articleLayouts.pageLayouts"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "magazine.articles.articleLayouts.pageLayouts": "2d641b7c-3d74-4cfa-8267-d5a01ed2614b"
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```